# Youtubestandaloneplayer in recycleradapter error

Tags: android, youtube, android-recyclerview, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I want to use Youtubestandaloneplayer in my recycleradapter, but there is an error in "this",

```
if (pos == 0) {
    context.startActivity(YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent(this, DEVELOPER_KEY, VIDEO_ID));
}
```

Here is my code:

```
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private Context context;

    public int currentItem;
    public ImageView itemImage;
    public TextView itemTitle;
    public TextView itemDetail;

    public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        context = itemView.getContext();
        itemImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
        itemTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
        itemDetail = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_detail);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int pos = getAdapterPosition();
                if (pos == 0) {
                    context.startActivity(YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent(this, DEVELOPER_KEY, VIDEO_ID));
                } else if (pos == 1) {
                    context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.naver.com")));
                } else if (pos == 2) {
                    context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.daum.net")));
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I don't know where I need to change. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass activity to your RecyclerView Adapter then change this into activity.
Example:  In your activity (Where you call recyclerview)
`adapter = new ExampleRecyclerAdapter(CurrentActivity.this, data);`

In your RecyclerView Adapter:

`Activity activity;
ExampleRecyclerAdapter(CurrentActivity activity, Data data) {
this.activity = activity;
}`

then replace in your code `this` into `activity`

```
context.startActivity(YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent(activity, DEVELOPER_KEY, VIDEO_ID));
```

}

Hope may be this work for you.